# Linked images (cells copied from other spreadsheets pasted as linked image) do not show in Excel Web Acess Webpart on SharePoint page

Tags: excel, web-services, sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-online

I uploaded Excel file with multiple spreadsheets and a Summary sheet(just another spreadsheet) containing charts + images linked from other spreadsheets on SharePoint. Then I added Excel web access webpart in page and in properties gave the marked **Print_Area** of my Summary sheet to show.

Everything shows normal from the spreadsheet's print area except the linked images. They do not appear. However if I just copy these cells from other spreadsheets and paste as a copy and not a linked image it shows on SharePoint page. Is there a workaround because the data updated in one spreadsheet is difficult to be copied again n again to dashboard(summary sheet).

[Copied cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvgD3.png)

[Pasted as Linked Image so that data doesn't need to updated on main sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c51s4.png)

[Print_Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmgpc.png)

[Excel Webpart properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hholV.png)

[SharePoint page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIi3s.png)

Charts and images in Summary spreadsheet show but cells copied from other spreadsheets and pasted as "Linked image" do not show in Excel Webpart

Comment: Please somebody reply... its pretty urgent

Comment: Answered here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/250100/linked-images-cells-copied-from-other-spreadsheets-pasted-as-linked-image-do-n